# Cannot get radio buttons to return correct value

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

I cannot get my radio button to return the correct value when it's emailed to me. I completely self-taught and basically just search these forums and copy / paste code until I make things work but this one has me stumped as to what i've done wrong!

I'm making a rsvp form for my wedding website and everything else returns fine but I just get "Options: YES" no matter whether they click attending or not attending.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary btn-default btn-lg shadow border">
    <input type="radio" name="options"  value="YES" id="contact-options"> ATTENDING
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary btn-default btn-lg shadow border">
    <input type="radio" name="options"  value="NO" id="contact-options"> NOT ATTENDING
  </label>
  </div>
```

The PHP is this:

```
<?php

$address = $_POST['emailAddress'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$options_value = $_POST['options'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$messagediet = $_POST['message2'];
$subject = 'You have been contacted by ' . $name;
$body = 'Name: ' . $name . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . 'Email: ' . $email . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . 'Options: ' .$options_value . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL .$message . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL .$messagediet;
$headers = 'From: ' . $email . PHP_EOL . 'Reply-To: ' . $email . PHP_EOL . 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' . PHP_EOL . 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . PHP_EOL;
mail($address, $subject, $body, $headers);

?>
```

And the main.js file has the following:

```
 function fn_contactForm() {

    var $form = $('#contact-form');

    $form.on('submit', function(e) {

      var $input = $form.find('input, textarea');
      var contactNameVal = $('#contact-name').val();
      var contactEmailVal = $('#contact-email').val();
      var contactOptionsVal = $('#contact-options').val();
      var contactDietMessageVal = $('#contact-diet').val();
      var contactMessageVal = $('#contact-message').val();
      var $contactNotice = $('.contact-notice');
      var $submitButton = $form.find('button[type="submit"]');

      e.preventDefault();

      if (contactNameVal == '' || contactEmailVal == '' || contactMessageVal == '' || contactDietMessageVal == '') {
        $contactNotice.stop(true).hide().html(_contactInputError).fadeIn(500);
        $input.each(function() {
          if (this.value === '') {
            this.focus();
            return false;
          }
        });

      }

      else if (!fn_formValidation(contactEmailVal)) {
        $contactNotice.stop(true).hide().html(_contactEmailError).fadeIn(500);
        $('#contact-email').focus();
      }
      else {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'assets/php/contact.php',
          data: {
            name: contactNameVal,
            email: contactEmailVal,
            options: contactOptionsVal,
            message: contactMessageVal,
            message2: contactDietMessageVal,
            emailAddress: _contactEmail
          },
          success: function() {
            $contactNotice.stop(true).hide().html(_contactSuccess).fadeIn(500);
            $form[0].reset();
            $input.blur();
          }
        });
      }
      return false;

    });
  }
```

Any help is very welcome, have searched for answers on here and although it's been answered before any answers i've tried just make it look worse!

Many thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

make HTML file as follows :

```
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
   <label class="btn btn-secondary btn-default btn-lg shadow border">
    <input type="radio" name="options"  value="YES" id="contact-options1" checked="checked">ATTENDING
   </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary btn-default btn-lg shadow border">
    <input type="radio" name="options"  value="NO" id="contact-options2"> NOT ATTENDING
```

and .js file as follows:

```
 function fn_contactForm() {

var $form = $('#contact-form');

$form.on('submit', function(e) {

  var $input = $form.find('input, textarea');
  var contactNameVal = $('#contact-name').val();
  var contactEmailVal = $('#contact-email').val();
  var contactDietMessageVal = $('#contact-diet').val();
  var contactMessageVal = $('#contact-message').val();
  var $contactNotice = $('.contact-notice');
  var $submitButton = $form.find('button[type="submit"]');
  var contactOptionsVal;
if (document.getElementById('contact-options1').checked) {
contactOptionsVal = document.getElementById('contact-options1').value;
   checked="checked" }else{
contactOptionsVal = document.getElementById('contact-options2').value;
 }
e.preventDefault();

  if (contactNameVal == '' || contactEmailVal == '' || contactMessageVal == '' || contactDietMessageVal == '') {
    $contactNotice.stop(true).hide().html(_contactInputError).fadeIn(500);
    $input.each(function() {
      if (this.value === '') {
        this.focus();
        return false;
      }
    });

  }

  else if (!fn_formValidation(contactEmailVal)) {
    $contactNotice.stop(true).hide().html(_contactEmailError).fadeIn(500);
    $('#contact-email').focus();
  }
      else {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'assets/php/contact.php',
      data: {
        name: contactNameVal,
        email: contactEmailVal,
        options: contactOptionsVal,
        message: contactMessageVal,
        message2: contactDietMessageVal,
        emailAddress: _contactEmail
      },
      success: function() {
        $contactNotice.stop(true).hide().html(_contactSuccess).fadeIn(500);
        $form[0].reset();
        $input.blur();
      }
    });
  }
  return false;

});
 }
```

Comment: This worked well but then I refreshed the page and tried again and now when I click submit it just reloads the page and doesn't send the email?

Comment: is it retrieving the values from the form ?

Answer (score 0):

first thing first "ID"s are identical so you must not use same ID in the same page twice.
what you have scoped is same ID so javascript will bring back the first value that it found and that is "YES"

for your answer you must get

```
$("form input[type='radio']:checked").val();
```

in your case is

```
$("#contact-form input[name='options'][type='radio']:checked").val();
```

and change the id of your radio input to something different

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix would be to select the `checked` one with

`var contactOptionsVal = $('#contact-options:checked').val()`

But, in order to follow the rule that you can't have more than one element with the same id, change the `id="contact-options"` in both places to `class` like: `class="contact-options"` then you can select with jQuery

`var contactOptionsVal = $('.contact-options:checked').val();`

Also, if no radio button is checked, then `contactOptionsVal` will be `undefined`, and you can check for that for submit with `if (contactOptionsVal === undefined) ...`